# ReactJS onClick event cant call its function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have problem here with this.greet() is undefined i have to bind onlick event dirrently to work, any ideas how to fix it ?

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Example1 extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.message = {
            greeting: 'Hello',
            name: 'World',
        };
    }

    greet() {
        const { greeting, name } = this.message;
        console.log(`${greeting} ${name}!`);
    }

    onClick() {
        try {
            this.greet();
        } catch (e) {
            console.error('Why have I failed? Can you fix me?');
        }
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.onClick}>Greet the world</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

i have tried many other ways but it didnt work out anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You lost `this` reference, you have to bind your functions:

```
<button onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>Greet the world</button>
```

or pass an arrow function

```
<button onClick={() => this.onClick()}>Greet the world</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting `undefined` as a value for `this.greet()` is because the `this` keyword in JS references the current object and in this case it doesn't exist and so `.greet()` method is actually attached to the window object. The solution you used as you described with binding works because `bind` attached the method to the current object context. Now, if you don't want to bind methods, you can use arrow functions like so:

```js
import React from 'react';

export default class Example1 extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.message = {
            greeting: 'Hello',
            name: 'World',
        };
    }

    greet = () => {
        const { greeting, name } = this.message;
        console.log(`${greeting} ${name}!`);
    }

    onClick = () => {
        try {
            this.greet();
        } catch (e) {
            console.error('Why have I failed? Can you fix me?');
        }
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.onClick}>Greet the world</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This works because the value of `this` is inherited into the local scope of the methods of the component class.

Comment: Thanks, i appreciate the detailed explanation

Answer (score 1):

if you want have "this" in your class component you should add props inside constructor invocation and also into the super

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.greet = this.greet.bind(this) // need's to be bounded
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is `this` keyword.
This is because of the way `this` works in javascript.

> `this` loses it's context when it gets used in callbacks.

There are two solutions for this problem. But I would recommend the arrow function solution the most.

1. Bind this in the `onClick` callback.

   ```
    onClick() {
        try {
            this.greet();
        } catch (e) {
            console.error('Why have I failed? Can you fix me?');
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>Greet the world</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
   ```
2. Use arrow functions for defining callbacks, ( personally recommended )

   ```
    onClick = () => {
        try {
            this.greet();
        } catch (e) {
            console.error('Why have I failed? Can you fix me?');
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.onClick}>Greet the world</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

First your function signature should be descriptive and then you can call the function like this

```html
                <button onClick={this.onClick()}>Greet the world</button>
```

Comment: This will result in calling the function once when the button is created instead of firing on the click event.

Comment: Yes you can pass as an arrow function like this
()=>this.onClick()
In that way it will be called when it will call